# Start (open) ListActivity without putExtra

Tags: android, listactivity

I am trying to open a list activity in two ways, (both from different activity A)
In one method I use putExtra(String name, String value) to populate the listActivity with sqlite.

This works perfectly awesome.

But now with another button, I am trying to open this list activity without putExtras (just viewing it) but i get a Force Close with Null Pointer Exception for this,

Can any one provide me some solutions for this, thanks in advance...

Comment: Please show us the source-code of the onCreate method you're using in the Actiivty that you're trying to open, and please include the output from logcat so that we can get the details on your NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

In your List activity, you're doing something like this yeah?

```
String passedValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

In the case when you don't putExtras() , `passedValue` is null, so trying to use this string will give a NPE. So if you want to use `passedValue`, you might want to do this:

```
  if(passedValue != null) 
       doSomethingWith(passedValue);
```

Comment: Wow! that worked, thanks for the help. Though i have one more problem, From (Activity A) if i don't use `startActivity(listIntent);` after giving it a putExtra, the values are not sent to the other (Activity B)...! **Can we use putExtra without starting a a new activity, but send the values?**

Comment: No sorry that is not possible, alternatives to do this are : using `SharedPrefrences` or storing your data in the `Application` class.